# How to get page source that is loaded through AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, parsing

I am using data scrapping technique(Parsing) in php to get the data from a web page using html_dom class. This page has some AJAX method to load more data when we scroll down the page but in page source there is only data that loads first time mean when we browse the page first time.

So my question is how to get the all page source that loads through AJAX??

Thanks

Comment: Utilizing the AJAX call in page you scrape would be quite a trick. You might be able to parse the call and run it, but you'd likely run into all sorts of issues. Whose content are you stealing?

Comment: Actullay i want to get the data from a shopping cart website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, you could use developer tool or <kbd>F12</kbd> button. Then go to `network` tab and tick the `preserve log` button and select the `XHR` tab to see which source is being loaded in that page.